# top:-50% not working?

Tags: html, css

Working on a my example from this [tutorial](http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html) for making a unique CSS for my website, I found a trouble in the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmeyb/6/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="outerContainer">
      <div class="innerContainer">
          <div class="element"><a href="#">Finally over four lines, all the code is the same for each list</a></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.items .outerContainer
{
    height: 180px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    position: relative;    
}

.items .outerContainer .innerContainer
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    background-color:red;    
}

.items .outerContainer .innerContainer .element
{
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
```

why `top: -50%;` of `.items .outerContainer .innerContainer .element` doesnt "move" the element to the top? If I write `top: -20px` for example works well, but I want %.

Why? And how can I fix it?

Strange, it works only on IE7 :)

Comment: hmm... -50% of what though? It's relatively positioned, so I'm not sure it can distinguish what -50% means in terms of distance to move the element.

Comment: I deleted my post but because it was exactly what he said ^

Comment: But this works well on IE7... http://jsfiddle.net/Cmeyb/7/ why there it works? lol

Comment: If I add height: 50px; to the div relatively positioned, nothing change...

Comment: add `height:50px` to `.items .outerContainer .innerContainer`. that is the outer container, check out Jabberwokie's answer.

Comment: But I can't add "manually" the height of the children to the parent. It should take automatically from children.

Comment: Well that's what you'll have to do. You have to give context to the percentage. If I told you to stand up right now and move 50% to the north, would you know how far to move?

Comment: so the question can be reverted : why on IE this works? Strange...

Comment: I can put the whole context on pecentage. So, how can I do this scenario that align the text in the middle?

Comment: Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` along with `vertical-align:middle` :) [http://jsfiddle.net/Cmeyb/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmeyb/10/)

Comment: Also, for your theory, height: auto; should works as well (it get the actual height). But in fact it doesnt...

Comment: Not really, on Firefox it doesnt works! (and on IE the text is not vertical aligned :))

Comment: well it's hard to say what you actually want to accomplish... in the tutorial you link to it uses the technique I suggested (vertical aligning using table and table-cell), but you're breaking the way that technique works by positioning it negatively.

Comment: I want to have the same code without the IF statment. Theorically, if works with IE6, MUST works with every other browsers :) So avoid display:table /table-cell...

Comment: IE6/7 is not something you want to compare against. If you look up browser stats IE6 isn't even on the map and IE7 is around 1% and declining. Sorry I can't help any further, but it's good to know these numbers when factoring in the time and effort you're going to spend trying to develop for these users.

Answer (score 4):

Moving an element by percentage requires the containing element to have a height attribute. So if you put height:90px; (Which I gather is correct as the item is 180px high and the innercontainer should be 50% from the top) it should work.

Comment: Check this on IE(7) : http://jsfiddle.net/Cmeyb/7/ it works as well. Can't believe it works there...